# ShellView or MainWindow as the master view in application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `View` base class, derived from `UserControl` that I use for all views. It allows for later addition of shared functionality to all my views without code duplication. I have now worked up to a level where I have an application whose top level views comprise only a 'NavBarView' and a 'WorkingView'. The latter is empty and merely a host for other child views provided by MEF plugins.

My question is, is it enough to host these two views in the `MainWindow` 'view' of the application, or should I rather create a `ShellView` containing them, and have that as simply the only child of `MainWindow`?

Comment: Make your comment an answer please, it's 'accepted'.

Comment: ok I will do when I get back to my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget, the purpose (of MVVM, MVC, MVP, et al) is to expose testable UI. In my case for an MVP WinForms application I simply have abstracted the implementation of actually showing views (as in, the underlying Forms etc). I would suggest `MainWindow` will suffice for bootstrapping, but if you intend to put substantial logic in it then go with `ShellView` in order to later test that logic. To me it sounds as though this is thin and I would personally start with `MainWindow` to get up and running. You can always refactor later.